# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) error in VirtualBox

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

Every time I try to run something in VirtualBox it keeps giving me an error, and I can't figure out how to fix it. I don't know how to fix it, and please be as detailed and easy to understand as possible, so I on't get confused. This is the error.

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not   
loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv  

Please reinstall the kernel module by executing '/sbin/vboxconfig' as root.
```

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Comment: The error message suggests to run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` in a terminal. How did you install virtualbox?

Comment: I installed it with the .deb file that you download from Oracles website

Comment: I also get this when I try that There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.

Answer (score 2):

Lets try these steps:

1. Install needed build tools:

   ```
   sudo apt install build-essential
   ```
2. Build the kernel modules for virtualbox:

   ```
   sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
   ```
3. Relaunch virtualbox.

Comment: `vboxdrv.sh: You must sign these kernel modules before using VirtualBox:`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1438279/how-to-sign-a-kernal-module-ubuntu-18-04